# Find direction of angle between 2 vectors

Tags: vectors

I have successfully calculated the magnitude from one vector to another using:

$$\cos^{-1} \left(\frac{u \cdot v}{||u||\,||v||}\right).$$

However this does not tell me whether this angle is left or right, positive or negative.

I need this for a game I am creating in which I need to use where a ship is facing and where I want it to face (relative position of the destination) but I need to know if the ship needs to turn left or right.

How do I modify or extend this formula to add a direction to it?

Comment: Just to elaborate: I could convert the vectors to angles and then work it out however I need a more efficient solution since this will be used by a real-time application.

Comment: Note, $\cos$ in this case gives you the angle between your two vectors, it doesn't necessarily have a direction. What would help is if you had a vector (perhaps the x-axis, or y-axis. Depending on what you want to achieve), and use that as a reference. By going counter-clockwise from the x-axis (imagine traversing a unit circle), you could determine the angle between the vector with the less steep slope, then the angle between your two vectors and add them together. Does that help?

Comment: @JeremyUpsal I believe this question is different: the OP is asking for a way to determine which side of the original vector the new vector lies: to the right or to the left.

Comment: You are right, I am sorry I will delete my comment.

Comment: @David Your answer works, but I have a doubt about it's performance. I will do a performance test to investigate the 2 methods I currently know about but I suspect neither is sufficient. I realise the PC performance doesn't fit in a maths forum but I don't know where else I should go.

Comment: @MrUniverse I assume your game is top-down perspective? You can use the cross product to do what you want. I'll post an answer up.

Comment: @MrUniverse, if you are programming something, note that all of these are arithmetic operations. I wouldn't micro-optimize on such operations. There are much larger parts of your programs that will serve as the bottleneck. Arithmetic operations like these won't be the bottleneck of your program.

Comment: @MrUniverse, further note that $\arctan(\text{slope})$ would be the angle in question between the x-axis and your lower steeped vector, so a reference vector is not even needed.

Comment: @David I was actually breaking up a 3D space-simulation problem into pitch and yaw components.

Answer (score 3):

I assume your game uses a top-down 2D perspective, so that you are storing your vectors $\vec{u}, \vec{v}$ as tuples

$\vec{u} = (u_1,u_2)$

$\vec{v} = (v_1,v_2)$

where $\vec{u}$ is the direction the ship is initially facing, and $\vec{v}$ is the direction you want it to face.

You can check to see if $\vec{v}$ lies to the left or to the right of $\vec{u}$ using the formula

> $\delta = u_1 v_2 - u_2 v_1$

if $\delta$ is positive then $\vec{v}$ is to the left of $\vec{u}$, if $\delta$ is negative then $\vec{v}$ is to the right of $\vec{u}$.
If $\delta$ is zero then $\vec{v}$ is in the opposite direction to $\vec{u}$.

Comment: I will check it out and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: No probs. I didn't see your comment about 3D simulation until after this answer was posted. But since pitch and yaw are rotations in a plane, this method will still work, though the linear algebra might become slightly more involved depending on exactly how you're modelling the position of the ship. It's hard to give exact formulas without knowing specifics, so if you have more questions feel free to ask.